# Assign width to half available screen width declaratively

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it possible to assign a widget width to half the available screen width, and do it using declarative xml?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

If your widget is a Button:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="somebutton"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm assuming you want your widget to take up one half, and another widget to take up the other half.  The trick is using a LinearLayout, setting `layout_width="fill_parent"` on both widgets, and setting `layout_weight` to the same value on both widgets as well.  If there are two widgets, both with the same weight, the LinearLayout will split the width between the two widgets.

Comment: Better use android:layout_width="0dp" for both child elements, avoiding sizing them twice.

Comment: I never got why you had to declare the layout_width="0dp"

Comment: You can also use <Space /> on the later versions of Android as fillers. I think View is a little lighter than TextView if you just intend to use it as a filler. layout_width="0dp" is actually the recommended approach according to Android documentation.

Comment: @Andrew: because this way the layout renderer does not try to work with the layout_width of the component, it skips directly to sharing the extra width according to weights.

Comment: As a side note I just tried using layout_weight with a tableview, works great there as well!!

Comment: How would you extend this method to enable an nth width of the screen?

Answer (score 61):

## Using constraints layout

1. Add a Guideline
2. Set the percentage to 50%
3. Constrain your view to the Guideline and the parent.

[image]

If you are having trouble changing it to a percentage, then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46295558/3681880).

#### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: I'm new to android and almost every spinner answer I find for my questions uses RelativeLayout which i see in the Legacy section in Android Studio. Your answer is simple, fast and very user friendly. Thanks you very very much.

Answer (score 19):

give width as 0dp to make sure its size is exactly as per its weight
this will make sure that even if content of child views get bigger, they'll still be limited to exactly half(according to is weight)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
     >

    <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click me"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>


    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think that android:layout_width="0dp" is correct but setting each weight to 0.5 and weitghtSum to their sum it's not needed. Seems like you just need to have the same weight on both child views..

Answer (score 5):

Another way for single item in center, which fill half of screen:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

       <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textD_Author"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Author : "
    android:textColor="#0404B4"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textD_Tag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Edition : "
    android:textColor="#0404B4"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btbEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Edit" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Delete" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For Layouts inside of `Constraintlayout` one can use

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="x"
```

for vertical arrangements and

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="y"
```

for horizontal arrangements where `0<=x,y<=1`