# Button half width of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a single button in a linear layout.  I want the button to take up half the width of its parent.  Is there a way to do this in the layout xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCollect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My question is much like this one [Assign width to half available screen width declaratively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2581481/758074) except I only have a single button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign width to half available screen width declaratively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581481/assign-width-to-half-available-screen-width-declaratively)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yep, the solution is very similar to that question, but you also want to set the weightSum of the parent LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCollect"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Oh, and yeah if you really want exactly half, starting with a 0dp width as others mentioned is usually a good idea.

Comment: I Have card view as parent and in that relative layout is there. I used above technique but not worked.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set a 0.5 (half) weight, and set the width to 0.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCollect"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"/>
```

Comment: I Have card view as parent and in that relative layout is there. I used above technique but not worked.

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar Make a new question, supply your own xml. Writing a comment under a 3 year old answer isn't going to yield fruit.

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me on Android L. I had to do wrap_content as below:

```
<Button
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/btnSignin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_signin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same as the question you posted, just use a dummy view instead:

```
<View 
android:weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```