# Buttons with half width of the screen in Android

Tags: android, layout, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Button half width of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470790/button-half-width-of-screen)

I want to create two buttons inside a linear layer (horizontal orientation), each one having the half width of the screen, and also a little margin.
I have this xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/Title" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/LeftButton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRight"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:text="@string/RightButton" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Well, all this code works perfectly for what I want but I get a warning about my two buttons. It says that ***"Nested weights are bad for performance"***. I know what is it about but I don't know how to change my layout in order to get rid of the warning (and improve performance, I suppose) and keep both buttons having the half of the screen.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: My problem is that I get that warning message

Comment: which warning message? show us...

Comment: "Nested weights are bad for performance"

Comment: not worry about that...refer this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/9431087/1139398

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I have to live with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/Title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/LeftButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRight"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:text="@string/RightButton" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that too, but the warning is still there

Comment: Use lint tool to find where is the erro becasue amp solution is the correct form to use layout_weight to avoid 2 builts of the views (buttons)

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp" >
```

replace the above with below":::

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp" android:weighSum = "2">
```

Comment: Not working. Maybe I should try Relative Layouts, even if I hate to re-edit the entire file

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmdSignup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Signup" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmdLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Login" />
</LinearLayout>
```