# Cardview half width of the screen

Tags: android, android-cardview

This is my layout. I am putting in a GridView. I want two columns in GridView which fill the width of the screen. Not able to make CardView layout to fill half of the screen. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470790/button-half-width-of-screen/9470815?noredirect=1#comment51626486_9470815) but no result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
card_view:cardElevation="2sp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:text="jalkdjlajflkdajf akjfdlajfljal alfjk"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quote"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="time started"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set `numColums` to 2 `GrridView` automatically make two column\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inflating the different layout file for your `GridView`. Your layout will be rendered as full screen width view. But when you define the no of columns or say span to the `GridView`, it will have two views side by side exactly the same which you want to achieve.

So, simply in your `GridView` tag inside xml just add

```
android:numColumns="2"
```

Or from java code.

```
mGridView.setNumColumns(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width of your  card view to "match-parent" and the grid layout manager will handle the rest