# Adjust width to half screen

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I came across this link :

[Assign width to half available screen width declaratively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581481/assign-width-to-half-available-screen-width-declaratively)

How to do the same in relative layout?
Here's the code: Trying linearlayout inside relative layout. But this doesn't work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="UID"
            android:textColor="#ffe5f1f1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffe5f1f1"
            android:hint="Enter UID"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:shadowColor="5"
            android:textColor="#ff009999"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="monospace" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="50"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffe5f1f1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#ff009999"
        android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Male" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Female" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinDept"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff009999" />
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what you actually want to dived into screen layout or it's widgets

Comment: make a form kind of layout which is compatible with all the screen sizes.

Comment: i don't understand your question. the linked question is about splitting a view in 2 halves. you have a dozen views in your linear layout. what are your trying to do?

Answer (score 57):

This is a nice workaround if you precisely need half, when using RelativeLayout. What you do is, make a fake invisible view centered in parent, and have left button be alignParentLeft and alignRight to that fake view and the right button vice-versa

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <View android:id="@+id/fakeView"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp" 
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignRight="@id/fakeView"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:text="Left"/>

   <Button 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@id/fakeView"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:text="Right"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Its really clever.

Comment: I agree, very clever. I would love to know if this is actually faster at rendering than using a LinearLayout.

Comment: Idk, probably not, but in more general view, but if youre using relative layout to begin with, this would be faster because you eleminate nested layouts

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the same thing with Relative layout which should work for you.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="somebutton">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="Wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So I'll have to use Linear layout a number of times? I have almost more than 5 rows similar to it in a relative layout.

Comment: Have one Relative Layout inside which you can have Linear Layout which contains your all row let it be one,  two or 100.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to **urSus**'s answer, it's better to use a [Space](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) class instead of `View`:

```
   <Space android:id="@+id/fakeView"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp" 
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Comment: I disagree. Space is only available for api14+, which makes it virtually useless if you want to target a wide range of devices.

Comment: well, api14+ is 4.0+ and according to the latest platform distribution chart (http://goo.gl/fmFDJw), the amount of devices with api <14 is now about 15% which is already almost insignificant

Comment: if you find 15% is insignificant, good for you. also this chart only measures devices with access to google play store, which is far from being all the devices.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    plannerEditLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.plannerLayoutEdit);
    plannerEditLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    plannerEditLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (width / 2), height));
```

I use the same code for LinearLayout. Havent tried it out myslef for RelativeLayout. Give it a shot. Comment if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `layout_weight` to 1 and `layout_width`  to fill_parent like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
           
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="somebutton">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_height="Wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>
```

In above example used LinearLayout, set widget layout_width to "match_parent" and provide weight(to specify area to be occupy).

This solves your problem.

Comment: Nope. Every element has id defined . Doesn't matter with that.