# Make image appear half of the screen

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am having trouble to make my imageview appear half of the screen can someone help. here is my xml file.  It should take up half of the screen size and also the linear layout with the textview should be at the footer of the imageview.

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:background="@drawable/fond" >

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <WebView

            android:id="@+id/webcontent"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="151dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/image_actualitedetails"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:src="@drawable/six_yamaha" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/linearvideo"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="65dp"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_actualitedetails"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:background="#88FFFFFF"

        android:gravity="center"

        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fourdp"

        android:paddingRight="@dimen/fourdp" >


        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/text_actualites"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="TextView"

            android:textColor="@color/tabDark"

            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="75dp"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:background="@drawable/header" >

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/boutton_retour"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"

        android:background="@drawable/back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just replace your top relative layout for a linear layout and do the other I said in my answer. Is pretty straightforward:)

Comment: [Now you can use a Constrain Layout to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46296011/3681880)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use LinearyLayout to wrap your ImageView and another invisible View, and set layout_weight both to 0.5, then the ImageView should be half the size.

Here is an example for you showing how to set the image half the screen size

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the result

[image]

If you want to put your image in center of the screen, you can use the same idea and set proper weight to achieve your goal. Good luck!

Comment: provide me with an example please ?

Answer (score 4):

First you'll need to get the display dimensions at runtime

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
windowWidth = size.x;
windowHeight = size.y;
```

Then you can go ahead and set your imageView height and width parameters to half of those values

```
int orgWidth = yourImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
int orgHeight = yourImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();



//Use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams if your parent is a RelativeLayout
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
windowHeight / 2, windowWidth / 2);
yourImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
yourImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Comment: Your idea ain't bad, but is better avoiding runtime code in layout design.:)

Answer (score 4):

Just if someone wants landscape version its almost the same :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#ff0000" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/adele" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#00ff00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your imageview inside a LinearLayout with horizontal alignment, so you can use

```
android:weight = 0.5// this attribute for the image view will force the image to fill half  of the screen, counting of course with the linear layout as the top parent layout(filling the hole window)
```