# Cliping an image in imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an imageview an i need to clip image half in that imageview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="true"
                android:clipChildren="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hexagon_1"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: This is the image without any margin]

However if i add margin instead of clipping image got streched like below

[image]

is there anyway to clip my hexagon into half using xml and without using custom layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add

```
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:src="@drawable/hexagon_1"
```

Use **`android:src`** instead of **`android:background`** .
For more information read [**`ClipDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html).

For clip image, You should create custom clip drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable"
    android:gravity="top" />
```

Courtesy goes to [**`ClipDrawable`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18073632/3395198).

Comment: need to add this also

Answer (score 0):

[Not tested, but a guiding light]

`PercentRelativeLayout` might solve your problem. [Read more here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```