# How to display a particular portion of a layout on screen?

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-relativelayout

[image]I have to create to sliders(relative layout with background image)  which are partially displaying on the screen on the click of that slider it should move to right and fully displaying on the screen and on another click it should move towards left and partially displaying on the screen .

I have achieved this moving animation but my problem is that Relative layout appearing fully on the screen and I want it to be display only 80%.
I have gone through [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544327/make-image-appear-half-of-the-screen) tutorial.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: But in navigation drawer it fully disappears after swiping.. and I don't want it..

Comment: Hey Raptor my xml code is too big to fit in this box.

Though I am sending the only layout that I want it to be slide

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Relative_slide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t_imageno"
        android:background="@drawable/new_pink_tag_slider" >
    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: There are several implementations of the slide menu that you seem to implement. Take a look at https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Answer (score 0):

Use SlidingPaneLayout

SlidingPaneLayout provides a horizontal, multi-pane layout for use at the top level of a UI. A left (or first) pane is treated as a content list or browser, subordinate to a primary detail view for displaying content.

Check this : [SlidingPanelLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html)