# How to fill half of screen with image?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

I am making a simple app in android studio, which includes two images filling up half of the screen, one on each side. Almost like a split screen. I have used this link: [Make image appear half of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544327/make-image-appear-half-of-the-screen) to try and solve my problem; however, it only made the top half of the screen filled with an image and when i tried repeating the code it divided the screen into 3 parts with one more empty space. This is the code which is responsible for that:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView_swamp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:rotation="-180"
                android:src="@drawable/img" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: use the same layout_weight for LinearLayout

Comment: @Style-7 how do i do that? Do i just do android: layout_weight="0.5" somewhere?

Comment: any values but the same

Comment: @Style-7 you have me confused. I am not sure what to modify. Could you clarify?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean/3996104#3996104