# How to fill a screen with two images?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

I am making a simple app in android studio, which includes two images filling up half of the screen, one on each side. Almost like a split screen. I have used this link: [Make image appear half of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544327/make-image-appear-half-of-the-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1&answertab=scoredesc#tab-top) but it only makes an  image appear on half of the screen when i want an image on either half. I would want something like this.[image]

This is the code which i am using:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView_swamp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/img" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need all the extra views. For vertical split screen:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_swamp1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_swamp2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

For horizontal/lanscape split screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_swamp1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_swamp2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]