# how to have 2 relative layouts divided by half in activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

i want to divide my screen in half vertically, and do a different color in each half,

i was trying to use this solution mentioned in here>

[Android: 2 relative layout divided in half screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983335/android-2-relative-layout-divided-in-half-screen)

but it doesn't work for me.

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.alignmentActivities.Add_New_Project_Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_add__new__project_">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f00000"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="#00b0f0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

how can i achieve the desired effect of 2 layouts each takes half the screen vertical \ what am i doing wrong then the example mentioned in the link ?

Comment: Change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `match_parent`

Comment: do you want to divide screen vertically ?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout/32168421#32168421

Comment: What do you mean by "but it doesn't work for me"? What did you do exactly? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may Try to use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f00000"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#00b0f0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Output :

[image: Screenview]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute in your LinearLayout

```
 android:weightSum="2"
```

After adding this your code will work.
WeightSum attribute defines the total number of equal divisions you want it to be divided.If you want it to be divided into 3 parts, change its value as 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

       <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@color/red">
       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@color/white">
       </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

**Preview Image Link**

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JKTP.png
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to divide screen vertically than you need to use `android:orientation="vertical"` and in child layout use `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

check below **xml**,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f00000" >
    </RelativeLayout >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00b0f0" >
    </RelativeLayout >
</LinearLayout >
```