# Can ConstraintLayout perform the same effect like PercentLayout？

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout, android-percent-library

I am a Android developer from China(My English sucks...).
  I want to make effect like figure 1: A FrameLayout`s width and height is both 50% of the screen width,contains an ImageView. The ImageView`s width and height is both 50% of the FrameLayout.
  I have made it by using PercentLayout,but I want to use constraintLayout to achieve the same effect.How should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318228/how-to-make-constraintlayout-work-with-percentage-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ConstraintLayout work with percentage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318228/how-to-make-constraintlayout-work-with-percentage-values)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/leftGuideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/rightGuideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/wall"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRighttOf="@+id/leftGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```